# How can spark.version be different from installed pyspark version?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working in a Python virtual environment in which I have installed pyspark version 3.5.0:

```bash
$ pip show pyspark
Name: pyspark
Version: 3.5.0
Summary: Apache Spark Python API
Home-page: https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/python
Author: Spark Developers
Author-email: dev@spark.apache.org
License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Location: C:\Users\...\venv2\Lib\site-packages
```

However, when I run

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('get-version').getOrCreate()
print(spark.version)
```

I get

```bash
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
24/03/22 15:50:10 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
3.4.0
```

Now, which Spark version is it? How can I make sure I'm running Spark version 3.5.0?

Comment: Are you executing the script with python or spark-submit?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I'm actually running it via jupyter inside VSCode and that's the environment in which I need to get it working. But running it with python gives the same result.

Comment: I see you're using a venv. Is it possible you've got pyspark installed two different places at different versions?

Comment: Yes, but I'm running the Jupyter Notebook in that same venv.